# Закрыть окно, открытое в другом файле расширение chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, chrome-extension

Здравствуйте. Пишу маленькое расширение для chrome, и столкнулся с проблемой, что нельзя закрыть окно которой было открыто в другом файле.

mytrades.js

`var win = window.open(url_id,"Trade",menubar=yes,location=yes,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,status=yes");`

contentscript.js

`win.close();`

Если открыть и закрыть в одном файле - работает.

В один файл код совместить не получиться. Т.к. один нужно обновлять при открытии страницы, а второй при действии.

Манифест таков:

`"background": {
        "scripts": ["js/jquery.js", "js/mytrades.js"]
    },
"content_scripts": [{
        "matches": [""],
        "js": ["contentscript.js"]
    }]`

Как закрыть вкладку с другого файла ?

Comment: А пробовали поместить переменную **win** в глобальную область видимости? `window.win = window.open(url_id,"Trade",menubar=yes,location=yes,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,status=yes");`

Comment: Сделал - не работает. Делал так: `var win;
      window.win = window.open(url_id, "Trade", "menubar=yes,location=yes,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,status=yes");` Так же пробовал закрыть как `window.win.close();` так и `win.close();`

Comment: Если `contentscript.js` отрабатывает в открытом окне, то надо просто вызвать `window.close();`, если оно в фокусе. Вопрос поставлен невнятно, приходится додумывать. Сделать инъекцию JS из одного окна в другое - не выйдет.